# SED and GREP showing different results

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I'm trying to get the amount of requests in a specific range of time from my Apache log. I though it was quite easy doing that with `sed` however when I tried doing the same with `grep` I realised that `grep` shows more results than `sed`.

Here's the `grep` command I used:

```
#grep '26/Apr/2017:08:0[0-2]:[0-2][0-4]' access.log 

10.51.32.104 - - [26/Apr/2017:08:00:21 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 762 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
10.51.32.104 - - [26/Apr/2017:08:00:22 +0100] "GET /index.php?action=Login&module=Users HTTP/1.1" 200 6591 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
172.30.180.113 - - [26/Apr/2017:08:02:04 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 301 1906 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; ipMonitor 10.7)"
172.30.180.113 - - [26/Apr/2017:08:02:04 +0100] "GET /index.php?action=Login&module=Users HTTP/1.0" 200 21951 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; ipMonitor 10.7)"
```

And here's the `sed` command:

```
#sed -n '/26\/Apr\/2017:08:00:21/ , /26\/Apr\/2017:08:02:04/p' access.log

10.51.32.104 - - [26/Apr/2017:08:00:21 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 762 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
10.51.32.104 - - [26/Apr/2017:08:00:22 +0100] "GET /index.php?action=Login&module=Users HTTP/1.1" 200 6591 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36"
172.30.180.113 - - [26/Apr/2017:08:02:04 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 301 1906 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; ipMonitor 10.7)"
```

So, as you can see it's missing one access from 172.30.180.113 that matches the pattern.

What did I do wrong? Would have any other parameter in `sed` helped, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what you are using is [range of lines addressing](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3120/address-and-address-range/13752/specific-range-of-lines#t=201704271706348666068) with sed.. it will print all PAIRs of start,end ... instead, use single similar regex like grep one...

Comment: @Sundeep I find your explanation misleading. It sounds like **only** the pair of the two matching lines is printed. But the lines between them are also printed. I think the relevant point is that printing will stop with the first line matching the second regex. The second line which matches the end regex and all after are not printed. Your proposed solution however seems sound. If you agree, I would create an answer using both our input.

Comment: @Yunnosch - a comment on StackOverflow is no match for real, actual documentation. "*addresses for each command [are] indicated by [0addr], [1addr], or [2addr], representing zero, one, or two addresses.*" The word "pair" is frequently used to refer to two of something, and in this case, the syntactical errors in Sundeep's explanation should lead one to refer to real documentation. That said .. yes, you've nailed the "relevant point".

Comment: @Yunnosch you're right, I first mentioned it as range of lines and then used pair which might be confusing... regarding answer, you can always make an answer from comments... there was even a meta q&a on it, not able to find link...

Answer (score 3):

You are quite close to solving it using `sed`. That is a good start and I will encourage you in going that route.

Of course you could use `regex` but it has its limitation. Consider the range `08:00` to `09:59`, the regex will be easy `0[89]:[0-5][09]`. But if the range is `08:45` to `09:30`, then `regex` will not be your friend. Hence, my encouragement to use the range as you tried.

The limitation you have seen with `sed` is that the end range is met and `sed` has stopped processing from there. But we know that there will be more lines that fall within the end range.

```
sed -n '/26\/Apr\/2017:08:00:21/,/26\/Apr\/2017:08:02:04/{p;b};/26\/Apr\/2017:08:02:04/p' access.log
```

Breaking down the sed commands:

`/26\/Apr\/2017:08:00:21/,/26\/Apr\/2017:08:02:04/{p;b}`

This will `p`rint the line if within range and then `b`ranch to the end of the `sed` commands.

`/26\/Apr\/2017:08:02:04/p`

This will only get executed if outside the range in the previous `sed` command. This will take care of the extra lines that fall within the range but is not considered within range by `sed`.

The same technic can be used with `awk`.

```
awk '/26\/Apr\/2017:08:00:21/,/26\/Apr\/2017:08:02:04/{a=NR;print};a!=NR && /26\/Apr\/2017:08:02:04/{print}' access.log
```

The first command:

```
/26\/Apr\/2017:08:00:21/,/26\/Apr\/2017:08:02:04/{a=NR;print}
```

Will print the lines within the range and set variable `a` to the value of `NR` (current record number).

The second command:

```
a!=NR && /26\/Apr\/2017:08:02:04/{print}
```

Will print the remaining lines that are within range but `awk` considered outside of range.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know awk could do sed-style address ranges.

Comment: That was a great explanation alvits! That really did the trick in this case Thank you for that!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, you're searching for a range of expressions, and `sed` will match all lines from the first match of the start to the first match of the end. As a language of its own, `awk` provides more flexibility than `sed`:

```
start=26/Apr/2017:08:00:21
end=26/Apr/2017:08:02:04
awk -v "s=$start" -v "e=$end" '$0~s{m=1} $0~e{m=0; f=1; print} f&&$0!~e{exit} m' access.log
```

We've got 4 conditional blocks. First we check for a match on the start and set `m`. Then we check for a match on the end and unset `m`, set `f`, and continue printing. The next check is for `f`, as long as there's no match on the end. This indicates that we've finished all the matches for the end string and can quit. The final block checks if `m` is set, and prints if it is.

A more verbose version of the same program:

```
awk -v "start_date=$start" -v "end_date=$end" '
{
    if ($0 ~ start_date) {
        matching = 1;
    }
    else if ($0 ~ end_date) {
        matching = 0;
        finishing = 1;
        print $0;
    }
    else if (finishing) {
        exit;
    }
    if (matching) {
        print $0;
    }
}
' access.log
```

Thanks to @alvits for beating me over the head in the comments until I figured out a better solution!

Comment: I have to assume that looks a bit alien for me, but it is really nice and motivating to learn awk! Thank you for you detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a better way to do this (which I mention at the bottom). Since recommendations would be off-topic for StackOverflow, I'll just respond with an explanation as to what's going on within the code that you've provided.

Your `grep` command prints every line of input that matches the regular expression you've specified. While this works, it's sometimes difficult to specify ranges purely in regex. (How would you specify a range from Jan 10th to March 2nd?)

A `sed` command can be a tad more complex. Consider the following:

```
$ sed -n -e '/re/p'
```

This will print all lines that match the regular expression `re`. Basically the same as `grep`.

```
$ sed -n -e '/re1/,/re2/p'
```

This will print all lines starting with the first match of `re1` and ending with the first match of `re2`. This is what the sed script in your question is doing.  Note that this also has the potential to print lines that DO NOT match one of the regular expressions:

```
$ printf 'one\ntwo\nthree\nfour\n' | sed -ne '/one/,/three/p'
one
two
three
```

If you want to extract counts of lines in your logs using sed, I recommend an alternate approach. While `sed` is great for pattern matching, it doesn't provide tools that can interpret dates. Perl, or gawk, or even bash would provide more functionality, and be easier to understand/debug six months from now when you need to make changes to your code.